# Jbehave maintain global data across stories - for dependency/execution order

Tags: automation, automated-tests, bdd, jbehave, user-stories

Problem:
Before running A.story and B.story the Procondition.story must be run and finished because Precondition.story inserts data in the database which is then used by A.sotry and B.story.

There are few approaches I know to set this dependency but they are not applicable in this context.

1. 'Givenstories' annotation is not of much help because in this case Precondition.story will run twice, first time for A.story and second time for B.story which results Precondition.story failure second time saying the data which it tries to insert into the database already exist.
2. [Using Maven failsafe plugin](http://mdolinin.github.io/blog/2014/01/19/thucydides-plus-jbehave-plus-maven-run-tests-in-fixed-order/) This will certainly place the Precondition.story on top in the execution list but all these stories are run in multi-threading environment where there are 8 threads ready to grab the stories to run simultaneously. Thread 1 takes the Precondition.story but while that story is yet not completed A.story and B.story kick off by thread 2 and 3 that makes A.story and B.story fail.
3. Specify the story order overriding storyPath(): Does not work due to the same problem mentioned in #2 above.

Possible solution: How about maintaining the state of the Precondition.story say in a boolean variable preconditionCompleted. When the Precondition.story completes the preconditionCompleted is set to true. Then add a step in A.story and B.story at the beginning which does polling on preconditionCompleted every seconds until it becomes true and then execute the rest of the story.

For this purpose I need to know where can we declare such global variables to use across stories?

Comment: How about a static variable *somewhere*?

Comment: @Kristof yes that's one of the options, I am testing this at the moment using a static variable. I am bit concerned about guarding the state even if it is synchronised.

Comment: Agree. I needed something similar before. For passing several parameters between steps/scenarios, I implemented a singleton class, with synchronized maps in it(scenarioParams, storyParams), so that I could pass variables through them. I cleared scenarioParams in `@AfterScenario`, and storyParams in `@AfterStory`, so that they could have no effect on other scenarios/stories. You could do something similar with globalParams, of course you don't need to clear them at all. Good think is synchronized map will do the syncronization for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Singleton class, which will contain some object. This object can be locked in @BeforeStory method of Precondition.story and released in @afterStory. Then in A and B story in @BeforeStory methods, you can wait until this object is released and then execute them.

Another way that I can think of is to make custom order annotation, but then you need to create logic to process it.